# No module named 'schedule' schedule module not detected by pycharm

Tags: python, scheduler

hello I tried to use the schedule module but it seems like pycharm doesn't detect it or it was not installed properly.
I tried uninstalling it and reinstalling it but still didn't work also pycharm detects discord module.
if you could help me please.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Check if PyCharm is using the same python interpreter as you need it to. You can do that by going to settings->Python interpreter.

Comment: Why don't you install packages from within PyCharm? Much more convenient to my taste...